# Use LINQ to Process Elastic Search Results

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, elasticsearch

What is the most most-efficient method for using LINQ to process ElasticSearch Results?

I came across JSON.Net's [JObject Class](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/).

Is the JSON returned from ElasticSearch structured in a fashion that lends itself to proper LINQ Queries via the JObject Class?

Comment: @BrandonMoretz [It's OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). What's the harm in getting good answers in SO?

Comment: Although I've answered this myself to share my solution, I'd be happy to see others.

Answer (score 6):

**This is a complete solution on how to utilize LINQ to process the JSON query-results from the elasticsearch engine.**

**Connection Library - [PlainElastic.NET](https://github.com/Yegoroff/PlainElastic.Net)**

First off, I am using PlainElastic.NET for one single purpose: for connecting to my elasticsearch server. This library is very lean and contains concise GET, POST, and PUT functions. This comes into play below with the `client` connection object. `result.ToString()` provides the JSON response from the elasticsearch server. Just slap the DLL into your bin and add a reference.

**JSON Processor - [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/)**

I am using a great feature of NewtonSoft JSON.NET to facilitate LINQ queries. The library has a class `JObject` which provides a nestable, queryable structure to execute LINQ against. See the line below where I grab `HitCount` to see how nice it is to grab an individual value, and, of course, check out the LINQ query to see how to query against it. Remember, this is simply a data-structure that is the result of parsing a JSON string. Just slap the DLL into your bin and add a reference.

## Performing the Query against Elastic Search

```
'Execute the Search
Dim client = New ElasticConnection("localhost", 9200)
Dim result = client.Post("myindex/mytype/_search", elastic_query) 'elastic_query = well-formatted elasticsearch query (json string)'
Dim J As JObject = JObject.Parse(result.ToString())

'How many results were located? 
Dim HitCount = CInt(J("hits")("total"))

'What was the maximum score? Maybe you want to know this for normalizing scores to 0-100.
' - We make sure we have hits first
' - Also, make sure scoring is turned on. It might be turned off if an alternate sort method is used in your query
If HitCount > 0 AndAlso J("hits")("max_score").Type <> JTokenType.Null Then MaxScore = CDbl(J("hits")("max_score"))
```

## Processing the Results with LINQ

Now, use LINQ to provide a beautiful anonymous object for binding to Gridviews, DataLists, Repeaters, etc. I am intentionally providing an example of a non-trivial LINQ query. This example gets nested data (`Stores`, `Categories`)

```
Dim SearchResults = _
  (From X In J("hits")("hits")
    Select
      score = CDec(If(X("_score").Type = JTokenType.Null, 0, X("_score"))),
      boost = CDbl(X("_source")("_boost")),
      InstitutionID = CInt(X("_source")("InstitutionID")),
      Name = CStr(X("_source")("Name")),
      Stores = (From S In X("_source")("Stores") Select CInt(S("StoreID"))).ToList(),
      Categories = (From Z In X("_source")("Categories") Select CatID = CInt(Z("CatID")), CatName = CStr(Z("CatName")), InstitutionID = CInt(X("_source")("InstitutionID"))).ToList()
 Order By score Descending, boost Descending
)
```

**Now, you can bind to a Repeater, DataList, or Gridview**

```
MyRepeater.DataSource = SearchResults
MyRepeater.DataBind()
```

Comment: While this works, it's relying on a user-generated query. If you use linq to filter the results, it all happens client-side which sort of misses the whole point of having elasticsearch. I believe the OP wanted something to actually generate the es query from the link expression. There are nuget packages which solve this provlem (eg ElasticLinq)